# What league of legends file(s) contain my settings?

Tags: league-of-legends

I plan on uninstalling and reinstalling league to fix some un-relevant issues. However I do not feel like re-applying all my custom video\interface options. I also don't wish to remake my custom item sets for my champions. Which files would I need to save first to keep these custom settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\Config (*installdir\Config*)

[image]

***game.cfg*** contains the game settings like mousespeed, volume etc. I think this is what you need.

***input.ini*** contains all of the keybind settings that you have changed from the default.

Both can be opened with notepad.

Comment: @Michel Which (if any) of these files contains my custom itemsets?

Comment: @Ender the itemsets are found in the champions folder, with each champions set in its respective folder named after the champion. I'd upload pics but I'm at work at the moment. I assume this is the same on Mac too.

Comment: For anyone reading this later: as of patch 5.23, item sets are saved on the League of Legends servers, so you don't need to back them up if you're reinstalling or switching computers.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a Mac (osx) then, go to:

Applications -> League of Legends -> Right-click the icon -> Show Package Content -> Contents -> LOL -> Config

You'll find the following:

- Champions (folder)
- game.cfg
- input.ini

The `show package content`

[image: Applications]

The `Contents` Folder

[image: Contents]

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to manually copy over your client settings as they are now preserved on the League of Legends servers.

via [patch 5.22.](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-522-notes#patch-server-side-game-settings)